# How to make a checkbox switch with multiple custom colors in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I make a Bootstrap 5 switch that has a custom color?
Some checkbox switches I would like to have a different color than the default.
Most answers I can find online talk about how to change it site wide only, or change to images. I am looking for custom colors, ideally only adding a couple of new .classes to the forms.

from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#switches

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

Trying to simply override the relevant classes in the local CSS didn't seem to work for me.
[edit]

I was just trying to create another ccs and add it to the list.

```
.custom-checkbox-red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks to 'Md' answer, I see what I did wrong the first time, i had to add chain.

```
.form-switch.custom-switch-red
```

Comment: Colors are applied via `.form-check-input:checked { background-color: #0d6efd; border-color: #0d6efd; }` - _"Trying to simply override the relevant classes in the local CSS didn't seem to work for me."_ - can't help much, based on that. _Show us_ what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra class or a wrapper hare I am adding a class with default

```css
.form-switch.custom-switch-color .form-check-input {
    background-color: #a89291;
}
.form-switch.custom-switch-color  .form-check-input:checked {
    background-color: #a6150f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-check form-switch custom-switch-color">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

In CSS just override default color in case of focus and active you can also change color as per your requirement and project